# I'm trying to get a single value (an email address) from a html input to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
        
  if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
  mysql_select_db($dbname, $db);
  if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";

  $email = $_POST["email"];
  // Inserting these values into the MySQL table
  // we created above
  $query = "INSERT INTO Emails-prelaunch (Email) VALUES (" . $email . "')";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  // mysql_query() is a PHP function for executing
  // MySQL queries
  echo "<p>Thank you for entering an email!</p>";
```

This is what've done so far but it gives giving me HTTPs 500 error or a syntax error in insert into value line

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Be sure to use prepared statements and parameter binding, so **you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again,** such as the badly quoted `(" . $email . "')`

Comment: In addition to other mentioned errors `Emails-prelaunch` also is an invalid table name. It needs to be in backticks.

Comment: Try commenting code and running it until you get the error, then you know it will be the last line of code that isn't commented. Assuming you stick with that mysql, here is an error, you are missing a single quote: **('$email')**

Comment: @imvain2 There are a lot better debugging methods than commenting line by line. Since a 500 is being thrown the server's error log should have something, if not the reporting level should be adjusted/corrected.

Comment: just by quick glance you have a extra single quote (" . $email . "')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the test phases, you can add the following code to the beginning of the file and find out the reason for the errors.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO prelaunch (Email) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

// set parameters and execute
$email = "john@example.com";

$stmt->execute();
```

If you don't want to use prepared statement (even if you should), there is only a missing ' character because $email is a String :

INSERT INTO Emails-prelaunch (Email) **VALUES (**'" . $email . "')"

Comment: Now it works but the email is not added to the database and the page gives me 404